# Define anotation at runtime

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I have this method in my application and I want to authorize to execute this method only users which have permssions `1,2`  in a specific organization. I have overriden method `hasPermission` to check based on `userid` and `organizationId` if he has `1,2` permission in database but I cannot pass a variable `organisationId` in `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

```java
@GetMapping(value="api/v1/oroganisation/{organisationId}")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('organisationId','[1,2]')")
public String hello(){ 
    return "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the `organisationId` into your `hello()` method as a method argument using a `@PathVariable` attribute. You can then refer to `organisationId` in your `@PreAuthorize` expression by prefixing it with a `#` character, i.e. `#organisationId`.

Please see the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) section 15.3.1 for full details.